# How to get value after ' = ' using sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

How to get a value after `remember=` using shell script from the following case:

case 1:

```
    String= " password   sufficient  shape sha512 remember=5"
```

case 2:

```
     String= " password   sufficient shape remember=5 sha512"
```

How I use sed command to get a value after `=` from the both cases. the output should be 5

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Comment: `grep -i "sufficient" <<"$String" | sed 's/^.*remember=//' ` . this command works only for case 1

Comment: `grep -Po 'remember=\K[^ ]+'`???

Comment: -P is not working in my case

Comment: Try:
`echo ${string} | grep -oE 'remember=[[:digit:]]+' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`: just match whole the string with the `remember=` followed by the backreference. Inside the backreference match the characters you want to match the value. And substitute the whole string for the backreference.

```
String=" password   sufficient shape remember=5 sha512"
sed 's/.*remember=\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' <<<"$String"
```

would output:

```
5
```

With `bash`: Remove everything up until `remember=` and then remove everything from the back up until a space:

```
String=" password   sufficient shape remember=5 sha512"
a=${String##*remember=};
a=${a%% *};
echo $a
```

In `awk`: iterate over the arguments and check if it's an "remember". Then extract the data after the `=`:

```
String=" password   sufficient shape remember=5 def";
<<<"$String" awk '{ for (i=0;i<=NF;++i) { b=$i; c=$i; gsub(/=.*/, "", b); if (b == "remember") { gsub(/.*=/, "", c); print c; } } }'
```

Note: the both similar source lines from your question

```
   String= " password   sufficient  shape sha512 remember=5"
```

Both give me similar

```
bash:  password   sufficient  shape sha512 remember=5: command not found
```

error.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${string} | grep -Po "remember=[0-9]+" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'
```